# How to make table as shown in picture using Latex?

Tags: tables

To get table as shown in picture, I used following tex code but resultant table is not as shown in picture, what corrections are required in tex code to get similar result.

1) Table Image (Picture):[image]

2) Tex file:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{collectbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sqbox}{%
    \collectbox{%
        \@tempdima=\dimexpr\width-\totalheight\relax
        \ifdim\@tempdima<\z@
            \fbox{\hbox{\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}\BOXCONTENT\hspace{-.5\@tempdima}}}%
        \else
            \ht\collectedbox=\dimexpr\ht\collectedbox+.5\@tempdima\relax
            \dp\collectedbox=\dimexpr\dp\collectedbox+.5\@tempdima\relax
            \fbox{\BOXCONTENT}%
        \fi
    }%
}
\makeatother
\title{try}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ |l | c | r | }
    \hline
   \sqbox{1}& \sqbox{2} & \sqbox{3} \\ \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

3) Tex output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please show what you've tried

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

The package `hhline` and `array` are your friends:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{||C{12mm}||C{12mm}||c||}
\hhline{|t:=:t:=:t:=:t|}
multiple lines  &   b               &   c   \\
\hhline{|:=::=::=:|}
d               &   multiple lines  &   f   \\
\hhline{|:=::=::=:|}
g               &   h               &   i   \\
\hhline{|b:=:b:=:b:=:b|}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```